# Setting regions in a Screen session

Tags: gnu-screen

I'm trying to get a 'Screen' with 4 tabs to split the screen into 4 regions.

I'm running 4 instances of bfgminer. One instance per USB Hardware miner. Unfortunately it has to be this way. So I'm trying to get all 4 outputs on 1 screen.

I am starting up screen with the following config file, to give me 4 tabs that I can switch between.

```
    screen -t  USB0
    select 0
    stuff "command /home/pi/Mining/bfgminer --scrypt -c miner.conf
    screen -t USB1
    select 1
    stuff "command /home/pi/Mining/bfgminer --scrypt -c miner.conf
    screen -t USB2
    select 2
    stuff "command /home/pi/Mining/bfgminer --scrypt -c miner.conf
    screen -t USB3
    select 3
    stuff "command /home/pi/Mining/bfgminer --scrypt -c miner.conf

    altscreen on
    term screen-256color                                          
    bind ','         prev                                                                  
    bind '.' next 
    #                                                                              
    #change the hardstatus settings to give an window list at the bottom of the    
    #screen, with the time and date and with the current window highlighted        
    hardstatus alwayslastline                                                      
    #hardstatus string '%{= kG}%-Lw%{= kW}%50> %n%f* %t%{= kG}%+Lw%< %{= kG}%-=%c:%
    hardstatus string '%{= kG}[ %{G}%H %{g}][%= %{= kw}%?%-Lw%?%{r}(%{W}%n*%f%t%?(%
```

I found it in an old post on here somewhere. And tweaked it a bit for my needs.

From reading the Screen man pages, I think that the 'Regions' function should allow me to get all 4 tabs split on 1 screen instead of having to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> just to look at the next screen.

How can I get Screen to show all 4 instances of bfgminer, on one single screen?

I'm going to be using ssh to get onto my Pi and check the miners from time to time, and it'll be a lot easier with only 1 logon, and screen to run.

Comment: if you can use tmux instead of screen

Comment: Been looking at the tmux man pages. It seems like a clone of screen. How would i be able to get tmux to startup and run all 4 instances with 1 command/shell script?

Comment: Well i found this - http://robots.thoughtbot.com/a-tmux-crash-course - Gonna have a read through and see if i can figure this out

Answer (score 2):

Rather than attempt to coax `screen` into merging the outputs I'd do the following.

1. Change each `bfgminer` so that they log to their own file like so.

   ```
   command /home/pi/Mining/bfgminer --scrypt -c miner.conf | tee bfgminger1.log
   ```
2. Then use the following `tail` command in a 5th `screen` so that I can watch the output from all 4 simultaneously.

   ```
   tail -f bfgminger{1..4}.log
   ```

Comment: That sounds like an option. But my only caveat would be that if need/want to alter some settings i will still have to ssh & screen into each bfgminer instance. Because im running things from my pi, im hoping to have screen autorun at boot, and show me all 4 screens

Answer (score 2):

I must recommend tmux in you case, I have my `tmux-setup-script`:

```
#!/bin/sh
tmux new-session -d -s rabin

tmux new-window -t rabin -n 'Server1' 'ssh root@10.x.x.x'
tmux new-window -t rabin -n 'Server2' 'ssh root@10.x.x.x'
tmux new-window -t rabin -n 'Server3' 'ssh root@10.x.x.x'
tmux new-window -t rabin -n 'Server4' 'ssh root@10.x.x.x'
tmux new-window -t rabin -n 'Server5' 'ssh root@10.x.x.x'

tmux select-window -t rabin:1
tmux -2 attach-session -t rabin
```

I also recommend you read the [Arch wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/tmux) for some nice option you can set in your `tmux.conf` file.

Edit:

You can split the same window into several panels,

```
# create a new session
tmux new-session -d -s XXX

 # will split the window horizontally
 tmux split-window -h -t XXX

 # will split the window vertically 
 tmux split-window    -t XXX

 # select the LEFT panel in the current window
 tmux select-pane -L  -t XXX
 tmux split-window    -t XXX
```

Comment: Can all of this be done through config file? So that its automatic

Comment: you can put all this commands in a shell script, and run it, just like the first example.

Comment: OK, so your saying....Run 4 instances on the Pi > Run tmux on my laptop > tell tmux to load 4 screens > each screen to ssh into the pi and load 'screen -d -r USB0'

Comment: Or do i run tmux on the pi and ssh into it from my laptop?

Comment: Run tmux on the RPi and from there connect to each USB device, then each time you connect to the RPi, just run `tmux att` and it will attach to the session.

Comment: Thank you. Now to play with configs and get things how i want them

Answer (score 0):

For `screen`, the commands you want are `split` and `focus next`, which creates a new region and moves focus to it, respectively. Run each of them before starting a new process.

If you have the vertical patch, `split -v` will work too, and might give you a nicer layout.